# Characterization of irreducible polynomials over finite fields - alternative proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

By accident I have found the following characterization of irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

**Lemma.** Let $g \in \mathbb{F}_p[T]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $m \geq 1$. Then, $g$ is irreducible if and only if $$g(Y) \equiv \prod_{i<m} (Y - X^{p^i}) \bmod g(X)$$
holds in $\mathbb{F}_p[X,Y]$.

Actually, this is just a reformulation of standard facts about the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ and Galois theory: a polynomial is irreducible iff the Galois group acts transitively on its roots. But when we phrase the characterization as above, this asks for a more direct proof. Is it available? **Can we prove the Lemma just by using the definition of an irreducible polynomial?** Also, is any constructive proof available?

Also, has this Lemma (literally, in this form as a relation in $\mathbb{F}_p[X,Y]$) appeared in the literature before?

Comment: Curious! I didn't find this in Lidl & Niederreiter. I want to check one other book, but it seems to be in my office.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Did you find something? 

Comment: I'm afraid not. I had a vague recollection that David Goss's book on function field arithmetic might have had something like this. But I don't see anything like this in there (He goes into Carlitz/Drinfeld modules as quickly as possible. I bought that book somewhat accidentally, and haven't really delved into it ever).

Comment: Thanks for checking :)

Comment: Wonder whether this extends to other cyclic Galois extensions in some appropriate way? The minimal polynomials $g_1(x)=x^3-3x+1$ and $g_2(x)=x^3+x^2-2x-1$ of $2\cos(2\pi/9)$ and $2\cos(2\pi/7)$ respectively have the property that if $r$ is one of the zeros, then $r^2-2$ is another. And both of these satisfy the congruence
$$g_j(y)\equiv (y-x)(y-(x^2-2))(y-((x^2-2)^2-2))\pmod{g_j(x)}$$
in the ring $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following uses only

- the definition of an irreducible polynomial;
- the division algorithm for monic polynomials; and
- the isomorphism theorems for rings.

For any $\mathbb F_p$-algebra $A$, let $F_A\colon A\to A$ be the map given by $F_A(a)=a^p$. Then $F_A$ is an $\mathbb F_p$-algebra endomorphism of $A$ which is injective (and thus, if $A$ is finite-dimensional over $\mathbb F_p$, bijective) if and only if $\text{rad}(A)=\{0\}$, *i.e.*, $A$ is semisimple.

Let $g(X)\in \mathbb F_p[X]$ be a given monic polynomial of degree $m$. Let $R= \mathbb F_p[X]/\langle g(X)\rangle$, let $q\colon \mathbb F_p[X]\to R$ be the quotient map, and set $x:=q(X)\in R$. Note that $R[Y]\cong \mathbb F_p[X,Y] / \langle g(X)\rangle$. Moreover, $R$ is an $m$-dimensional $\mathbb F_p$-algebra which is an integral domain if and only if $g$ is irreducible.Let
$$
p(Y) = \prod_{t=0}^{m-1}(Y-x^{p^t}) \in R[Y]
$$

**Proposition**:
The polynomial $g(Y)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_p[Y]$ if and only if $g(Y)=p(Y) \in R[Y]$.

We will prove the proposition using a sequence of Lemmas:

**Lemma 1**:
If $E$ is a field extension of $\mathbb F_p$ which contains a root $r_E$ of $g$, then if $S = \{r_E^{p^i}: i \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}\}$, it follows that there is some $k \leq m$ such that $S = \{r_E^{p^i}: 0\leq i <k\}$ and moreover if
$$
p_E(Y) = \prod_{t=0}^{k-1}(Y-r_E^{p^t})
$$
then $p_E(Y)\in \mathbb F_p[Y]$ and $p_E(Y)$ divides $g(Y)$ in $\mathbb F_p[Y]$. In particular, if $g$ is irreducible, then $g$ splits over $E$ and $g(Y)=p_E(Y)$.

*Proof*: Replacing $E$ by $\mathbb F_p[r_0]\subseteq E$ if necessary, we may assume that $E$ is finite over $\mathbb F_p$, and hence $F_E\colon E \to E$ is bijective. Since $g(Y)\in \mathbb F_p[Y]\subseteq E[Y]$, if $a \in E$ then $F_E(g(a)) = g(a^p)$. It follows that $g(r_E^p)=0$ and hence by induction on $n$ we see that $g(r_E^{p^n})=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$. Let $S = \{r_E^{p^n}: n\in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}\}$. Now $g(Y)\in E[Y]$ has at most $m$ roots, hence $S$ is a finite set. But then as $F_E(S)\subseteq S$ and $F_E$ is injective, it follows $F_E(S)=S$, and hence $S = \{r_E, r_E^{p},\ldots,r_E^{p^{k-1}}\}$ where $k=|S|\leq m$, and $r_E^{p^{k}}=r_E$.

Now by the division algorithm $(Y-r_E^{p^i})$ divides $g$ in $E[Y]$ for each $i \in \{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$, and thus, since $E[Y]$ is a PID and $\{(Y-r_E^{p^i}): 0\leq i \leq k-1\}$ are pairwise coprime, their product, $p(Y) = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(Y-r_E^{p^i})$ divides $g(Y)$. But

$$
F_E(p_E(Y)) = F_E\big(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(Y-r_E^{p^i})\big) = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(Y-r_E^{p^{i+1}}) = p_E(Y)
$$

It follows that the coefficients of $p_E(Y)$ are fixed by $F_E$. But if $a \in E$, then $F_E(a)=a$ if and only if $a$ satisfies $Y^p-Y=0$. Since the elements of $\mathbb F_p$ give $p$ roots of $Y^p-Y$, and $E$ is an integral domain, it follows $F_E(a)=a$ if and only if $a\in\mathbb F_p$, and hence $p(Y)\in \mathbb F_p[Y]\subseteq E[Y]$ . Since $p_E(Y)$ divides $g(Y)$ in $E[Y]$, it must do so in $\mathbb F_p[Y]$ (*e.g.*, because Euclid's algorithm will be unchanged by extending scalars) and thus if $g(Y)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb F_p[Y]$, then we must have $g(Y)=p_E(Y)$ and so $k=m$.

$\fbox{$\phantom{a}$}$

Lemma 1 proves the "only if" part of Proposition 1, since if $g$ is irreducible we may take $(E,r_E)$ to be $(R,x)$. For the other implication we need two more lemmas:

**Lemma 2**:
If $p(Y) \in \mathbb F_p[Y]$ then $p(Y)$ divides $Y^{p^m}-Y$ in $\mathbb F_p[Y]$.

*Proof*:
Let $h(Y) = \prod_{r=1}^{m-1}(Y-x^{p^r})$. If $p(Y) \in \mathbb F_p[Y]$ then
$$
0=p(Y)-F_R(p(Y)) = h(Y)(x^{p^m}-x).
$$
Since $h(Y)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $m-1$ it follows that $x^{p^m}-x=0$. But now $p(Y)$ is monic of degree $m<p^m$, so by the division algorithm in $R[Y]$ we have $Y^{p^m}-Y = p(Y).q(Y)+r(Y)$, for some $r(Y)$ with $\text{deg}(r)<m$. But then substituting $Y=x$ we find $0=x^{p^m}-x=r(x)$, and hence $r(Y)=0$ (since $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{m-1}\}$ is a basis of the $\mathbb F_p$-vector space $R$). Thus $p(Y)$ divides $Y^{p^m}-Y$ as required.

$\fbox{$\phantom{a}$}$

With this in hand, we can complete the proof of the other implication of the Proposition:

**Lemma 3**
If $g(Y)=p(Y) \in R[Y]$ then $g$ is irreducible.

*Proof*: Since $g(Y)\in \mathbb F_p[Y]$, if $g(Y)=p(Y)$ then by Lemma 2 it follows that $g(Y)$ divides $Y^{p^m}-Y$. Now $Y^{p^m}-Y$ factorizes into a product of distinct irreducibles, hence the same must be true of $g(Y)$. Thus we may write $g(Y) = g_1(Y).g_2(Y)$ where $g_1(Y)$ is an irreducible factor of $g(Y)$ of minimal degree and $g_2$ is coprime to $g_1$. It follows that $R=R_1\oplus R_2$ and $R_1 = \mathbb F_p[X]/\langle g_1(X)\rangle$, $R_2 = \mathbb F_p[X]/\langle g_2(X)\rangle$, and so $R[Y] = R_1[Y]\oplus R_2[Y]$. Thus $g(Y)=p(Y)$ in $R[Y]$ if and only if $g(Y)=p(Y)$ in both $R_1[Y]$ and $R_2[Y]$.

But in $R_1[Y]$, by Lemma 1 applied to $E=R_1$ and $r_E = x_1= X+\langle g_1(X)\rangle$, we see that if $m=q_1m_1+r_1$ then $p(Y) = g_1(Y)^{q_1}.p_{r_1}(Y)$ where $p_{r_1}(Y)=\prod_{i=0}^{r_1-1}(Y-x_1^{p^i})$. In particular, since $m\geq m_1$, the roots of $p(Y)$ in $R_1[Y]$ are precisely the roots of $g_1(Y)$, thus if $p(Y)=g(Y)$ in $R_1[Y]$ then the roots of $g_2(Y)$ must be a subset of the roots of $g_1$. But since $g_1,g_2$ are coprime, this is possible only if $g_2$ has degree $0$, that is, $g_2$ is a unit, and hence $g(Y)=g_1(Y)$ is irreducible.

$\fbox{$\phantom{a}$}$

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it. Your answer is only about one direction, right?

Comment: I wrote it that way, but I think the argument basically works to show the if and only if statement. I'll try and update it now.

Comment: Ok. I am already confused by the equation g(X)=0. Do you mean something else? Maybe R has the variable X?

Comment: And to be honest, I was looking for a proof which does not use the finite field with p^m elements and its properties. I thought that this is already clear from my question, but maybe it is not.

Comment: Thank you for the 2nd proof. It is clearer now. I have changed the proof a bit, since it had several unnecessary arguments by contradiction (and some inaccuracies as well). I just have one question about the direction $\Leftarrow$: Assume that $g(Y) = \prod_{i=0}^{m-1} (Y-x^{p^i})$ and $g = g_1 \cdot g_2$ is a factorization in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. You write that we can assume $g_1(x)=0$. Why is that? We know $0 = g(x) = g_1(x) g_2(x)$, but since $R$ not assumed to be an integral domain, how can we use this?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg you're right, the $\Leftarrow$ direction of the argument didn't quite work. I've updated the answer to fix that (essentially the fix is the new Lemma 2).